# What is the correct way to implement text filtering with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

I have a component with a list of ToDos with a SearchBar above to filter the ToDos. The ToDos are stored in the Redux store because I also need them in other components. But the SearchTerm is a property of the component state because I need it only in this component. In the `componentDidMount` hook I dispatch a action that causes fetching all ToDos from my remote server. I am using `mapStateToProps` and `connect` from react-redux. How to display just the filtered ToDos in the component? In `mapStateToProps` I don't have access to the component state to use the SearchTerm to filter all ToDos from the Redux store and send a filteredToDos prop to the component. Or is there a way to subscribe to changes to the ToDos prop in the component so that I can filter them when the ToDos are fetched from the server? Or should I put the SearchTerm in the redux store, so I can access it inside the `mapStateToProps` function? What's the cleanest solution to this problem?
Here is some code to illustrate the problem:

```
class StoreState {
    toDos: string[];
}

class ToDoList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { searchTerm: '', filteredToDos: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchAllTodos());
    }

    handleChangeText(searchTerm: string) {
        const filteredToDos = this.props.toDos.filter(toDo => toDo.includes(searchTerm));
        this.setState({ searchTerm, filteredToDos });

    }

    render() {
        return (
           <View>
              <TextInput onChangeText={ searchTerm => this.handleChangeText(searchTerm) } /> // SearchBar
              <FlatList data={this.state.filteredToDos}/> // List of filtered todo items
           </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: StoreState) {
  return { toDos: state.toDos };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ToDoList)
```

But now, when the toDos are fetched from the server and the toDos prop is updated, then the filteredToDos aren't updated. Is there a hook or something like that to subscribe to prop updates? Or should I put the SearchTerm in the store and write the `mapStateToProps` like this?

```
class StoreState {
    toDos: string[];
    searchTerm: string;
}

function mapStateToProps(state: StoreState) {
  return { filteredToDos: state.toDos.filter(toDo => toDo.includes(state.searchTerm)) };
}
```

What is the preferred solution?

Comment: If the ToDos and the search component are independent, storing the search term in the state would make sense. The ToDo component can then just filter based on that value from the state.

Comment: You need an action creator that handles the search and expects a single argument - the search term... Then dispatch that action from your Form component with the searchterm that you keep as local state as the argument...

Comment: @namsnath I have one ToDoList component that includes the SearchBar and a list of filtered ToDos below. And I have some more components that need to access the ToDos but that are irrelevant for this example.

Comment: @SakoBu I know how to outsource the SearchTerm to the Redux store. My question is if this is really the preferred solution because the SearchTerm is only relevant to this single component...Or if I should rather keep the SearchTerm in the local component state and try to filter the ToDo items either in the `mapStateToProps` or in a `toDosPropDidChange` hook if something like this exists...hope you understand my problem better now...

Comment: @ChristophHummler in that case, how about you try saving the search term to the store and filtering in your ToDos component. In case, you do not want to store to app state, try using local state in your TodoList component, that can be shared between the search and ToDos

Comment: It's difficult to understand your issue without seeing any code...https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Generally speaking - yes it's fine to keep local state (especially for forms) since no other component cares about that state...

Comment: @SakoBu Ok, but how to run the filtering logic when the data is updated (When the ToDos are fetched from the server, the toDos prop of the component is updated, because connect updates the prop for me, but the filteredToDos property in the component state isn't updated. That's why the ToDo list is still displaying the 'old' filteredToDos)

Comment: Please see minimal reproducible example link above

Comment: @SakoBu Ok, I hope you understand the question now.